# NSAllocateCollectable it is possible with iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm developing an iphone application and when I compile it I receive some warnings. The application works, but probably it is interesting to delete all the warnings no?

This is one of them, that I can't undersand, basically because I'm a "rookie" with iPhone SDK and this class comes from another code (free code).

The warning are:

> warning: implicit declaration of function 'NSAllocateCollectable'
>   warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

The code is this:

```
double *MatrixAllocateArray( NSUInteger rows, NSUInteger columns )
{
     // Allocate an array to hold [rows][columns] matrix values
     NSCParameterAssert(rows!=0);
     NSCParameterAssert(columns!=0);
     __strong double *array = NSAllocateCollectable(SIZEOFARRAY(rows,columns),0); //(WARNINGS APPEAR HERE)
     NSCAssert2(array!=NULL,@"falled to allocate %dx%d matrix",rows,columns);

     return array;
}
```

As you can see this function try to allocate a matrix, and it is called by another function.

```
double *MatrixAllocateEmptyArray( NSUInteger rows, NSUInteger columns )
{
     // Allocate a matrix array and fill it with zeros
     __strong double *emptyArray = MatrixAllocateArray(rows,columns);
     bzero(emptyArray,SIZEOFARRAY(rows,columns));

     return emptyArray;
}
```

And this is called by the function which I execute and need:

```
- (id)initWithRows:(NSUInteger)rowCount columns:(NSUInteger)colCount
{
     // Create an empty matrix

     return [self initWithAllocatedArray:MatrixAllocateEmptyArray(rowCount,colCount)
           rows:rowCount
        columns:colCount];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no garbage collector for iPhone programs.  Allocating collectable memory is pretty much meaningless in that sitaution, so you're probably out of luck.  You should probably fix your program and/or framework to use the traditional Objective-C memory management practices.  The reasons for your specific warnings:

1. `implicit declaration of function 'NSAllocateCollectable'`

   There is no declaration of `NSAllocateCollectable` for your iPhone app, so the compiler is going to fall back to the default C rules for implicit function declarations, meaning it will assume it returns `int`.
2. `initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`

   Because of the previous problem with the implicit declaration, your code looks to the compiler like it is trying to assign an `int` to a variable of type `double *` - implicit conversions from integer types to pointers are a cause for warnings.